# Centos 7.1: how to record from audio input (not microphone)

Tags: linux, centos, audio

I use centos 7.1. What application can I use to record audio input (not microphone) from sound adapter? For example I connect TV sound output to PC sound card input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Audacity` for that. In `Audacity`, you can select what you wish to use as input.

[image]

So your input would be visible here and you can select that. Moreover, I think it would be detected as Microphone only, nothing different. In that case, any other software might also do.

Answer (score 0):

Try install pavucontrol.

```
yum install pavucontrol
```

After installation, from menu open PulseAudio Volume Control

Here the input devices will be detected. The built-in volume control seem to face some problem. It worked for me.

[image]